# Flutter Web App Error: Unable to Load Firebase Messaging Library (firebase_messaging.js)

Tags: javascript, flutter, firebase

I am developing a Flutter web app, and I have integrated Firebase for messaging services. However, when I try to get a token from Firebase using the Firebase Messaging library, the app keeps loading indefinitely, and I receive an error about not being able to load "firebase_messaging.js".

Here's a snippet of my index.html file:

```
<!-- ... (previous code) ... -->

<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.1/firebase-auth.js"></script>
<script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/10.3.1/firebase_messaging.js"></script>

</body>

</html>
```

I have ensured that the Firebase configuration is correct, and I've also tried different versions of Firebase JavaScript libraries, but the issue persists. What could be causing this problem, and how can I resolve it?